# Count the number of occurrences of a string in a row

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a combobox which contains different values:

```
public static DataTable GetStates()
    {
        DataTable myStates = new DataTable();
        myStates.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        myStates.Columns.Add("Location", typeof(string));

        myStates.Rows.Add("1", "USA");
        myStates.Rows.Add("2", "USA");
        myStates.Rows.Add("3", "Canada");
        return myStates;
    }
```

I want this to be in BindStates function which will count the number of occurences of "USA" and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void BindStates(DataTable states)
{
    int numberUsa = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row in states.Rows)
    {
        if (row[1].ToString() == "USA")
        {
            numberUsa++;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(numberUsa.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using LINQ against the datatable. So what I'm doing is creating an IGrouping that is grouped by the second object in the DataRow ItemArray. The second step is to just count how many items are in the "USA" Group.

```
// Get datatable with data
var states = GetStates();

// Create grouping of rows
var grouping = states.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.ItemArray[1]).ToList();

// Count how many rows are in the "USA" group
var numOfUSA = grouping.First(group => group.Key == "USA").Count();
```

Obviously this code can be improved with null checking etc, this is just to get you started. Good Luck!

Comment: why not use Enumerable.Count? why not also row.Field<string>("Location")?